# Treat .php File as Root Folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, api, url-rewriting

So right now I have a index.php file that acts as an API in the root of a subdomain.

So if you go to http://some.domainname.com/index.php/items/ for example you get a response. 
However if you go to http://some.domainname.com/items/ you get a 404 error.

I'm assuming there is some .htaccess rewrite command I can add to make this work but I haven't had any luck finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example based on how Magento does it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It will effectively remove the `index.php` from your urls, but it won't stop anyone from accessing a file that actually exists, like `www.example.com/i-exist.php`

**Note:**
This is specifically geared toward a site whose urls alway end with a trailing slash `(/)`, like `www.example.com/index.php/somepage/`.  This is set with the `RewriteBase /` line.